# Service bus topic inserted duplicate message record for same MessageId

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

```
[FunctionName("MyProcess")]
public static void Run(BrokeredMessage currentMessage,[ServiceBus("mytopic",
    Connection = "ConnServiceBus")]ICollector<BrokeredMessage> mytopicDemo, TraceWriter log)
{
    string messageBody = currentMessage.GetBody<string>();
    BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(result);
    //extracted Id and Name from body using some code for simplicity making it as messageBody.Id and messageBody.Name
    brokeredMessage.Properties.Add("Id", messageBody.Id);    
    brokeredMessage.Properties.Add("Name", messageBody.Name);
    brokeredMessage.MessageId = "ZZ"; // I also tried GUID here messageBody.Id
    mytopicDemo.Add(brokeredMessage);

    ...
```

service bus unable to identify duplicate messageId message.

It isinserting multiple records for same messageId why?

It should avoid toinsert duplicate record if it is already present.[image]

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but does Topic have duplicate detection enabled and do you send duplicates short time one after another?

Comment: @Mikhail I'll leave this with you. I haven't used this api

Comment: @Mikhail duplicate detection is enabled but strange why not working properly :(
I have created new topic just to test with same duplicate detection setting it works it detects duplicate but this old topic is failed to identity duplicate.

Comment: @Neo Is the problem reliably reproducible on that old topic? Or just happened once? Could it be that the duplicate was detected, but rather the same message got processed twice (due to retry or smth)?

Comment: no duplicate detected..i send 2 messages with same messageId and I can see these 2 messages inserted into topic with same MessageId that should not be happened. as we have already message is present with that messageId

Comment: I'm sure there is no issue into code but it is into configuration , may be duplicate detection property is not set at the time of topic creation it is set/modified later.
I just want to understand root cause, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable causes might be

- If an application encounters a fatal error immediately after it sends
  a message, and the restarted application instance erroneously
  believes that the prior message delivery did not occur, a subsequent
  send causes the same message to appear in the system twice.
- It is also possible for an error at the client or network level to
  occur a moment earlier, and for a sent message to be committed into
  the queue, with the acknowledgment not successfully returned to the
  client. This scenario leaves the client in doubt about the outcome of
  the send operation.

Enabling duplicate detection solves this problem by discarding the duplicate messages.

The duplicate detection time history defaults to 30 seconds for queues and topics, with a maximum value of 7 days.

The duplicate detection time history must be large to detect as much as duplicate messages .Also note that the size of the window directly impact the queue (and topic) throughput.

Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection) for more information.